# require.js and bundles

Tags: requirejs, bundle, r.js

I created bundle config in my main configuration file

```
    bundles: {
        'staff-bundle-view-profile' : [
            'viewProfile/viewProfile',
            'viewProfile/viewProfileEducation',
            'viewProfile/viewProfilePublication',
            'viewProfile/viewProfilePlot'                
        ]
    }
```

When I try load one of modules from above list, for example viewProfile/viewProfile
 - as a result, require.js try load staff-bundle-view-profile.js

Of course I get 404 error.
What should i do to create this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bundles` configuration option is meant to be used to load bundles created with the [`r.js` optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html), or any optimizer that operates like `r.js` does. So you need to use an optimizer like `r.js` to create `staff-bundle-view-profile`. There are multiple ways to perform the build. Which way would be best depends on specifics of your project that are not in your question. You should read the documentation and the questions about `r.js` already asked on SO to figure out what would work best for you.

Comment: Thank you, I created bundles using r.js optimizor and now all ok. My second step - link it with grunt, but i think it is not difficult. (My project is average rich client application with knockout components/sammy.js etc., but in future i want find more modern framework, i think about vue.js instead knockout, and webpack instead grunt)